# Disable Chrome "Open with" dialog when redirecting to PayPal payment page

Tags: javascript, android-intent, paypal

On a website there is a "Submit order" button, which supposed to redirect users to PayPal payment page via `window.location.href`. When a user who has PayPal App installed on his Android clicks on this button in Mobile Chrome then a system "Open with Paypal, Chrome, etc" popup appears, which prevents redirecting until the user makes a choice.

The thing is if the user doesn't choose anything and just closes the popup then the redirection doesn't resume and the user stays on the same page and never gets to the PayPal payment page.

I believe this issue closely related to PayPal's desire to redirect users to their native app, which in some cases breaks UX. Is there a way to disable this behaviour at all? If not, maybe there are some hooks I could use to detect that the popup is closed without the choice being made?